# How to use @Resource annotation in servlet (or in any other Java class)?

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection, cdi

I am experimenting with Java Dependency Injection. Many questions here on SO talk about jndi resources being wired. But I think, a java class can be wired using `@Resource` annotation. I have a simple servlet in which I have two properties to be wired using CDI. I am using Tomcat6, Servlet 2.5, and Weld configuration.

**The servlet code:**

```
@Inject
private HikariConnectionProperties hikariConnectionProperties;

@Resource(name = "connectionProvider")
private IConnectionProvider connectionProvider;
```

However I get the code compiled, deployed. But, when there is a request for the corresponding servlet I get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name connectionProvider is not bound in this Context`.

But, I have `@Named` annotation for the `ConnectionProvider` class. **The same configuration works with `@Inject` for both the fields.**

So, my first question is how can I fix this issue? And is there any way that I can specify scope for a particular injection(using only annotations of JSR) without using Spring's `@Scope`? Any example is a great help as I am a newbie to CDI.

Comment: You could see [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/implementation.html#resources) `ConnectionProvider` should not be `@Named`, it should be `@Resource`, `@PersistenceContext`, etc.

Comment: @Everv0id Resource also doesn't work

Comment: So, what will happen if you remove `(name = "connectionProvider")` from injection point or add this to `ConnectionProvider` declaration?

Comment: @Everv0id Experimented both. ): No success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Resource` only works in Tomcat when you set up a resource in your container.  Here's a reference for your own sake: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

It expects that you're binding a JNDI entry called "connectionProvider" in Tomcat.  CDI does not bind elements to JNDI, it has its own internal mapping of objects to scopes.  `@Inject` works here as you likely have not setup a resource for this class in your resource configuration.